# What is this bug? Is it a pest?

Tags: pest-control, pests, bugs

The other day I asked [a question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/48691/japanese-squash-seedlings-are-going-limp) about keeping Japanese squash plants. Just now I discovered some bugs in the pot where I keep the squash plants. I saw maybe 10 of them creeping on or just below the surface soil in the pot. They are not large in size. Are they squash bugs?

My plants are all indoors and with winter in full swing all the windows have stayed shut, so the bugs must have come with the soil. I used half potting mix and half outside soil from a tiny park downstairs. They seem to be afraid of light, always trying to hide under something.

Should I worry about these bugs? Since just like my plants they are in my living room, should I worry about my furniture?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that I'd worry about the insects as far as hurting your plants, but I would worry about them establishing a colony in your home. My advice is to, as soon as possible, BRIEFLY take each plant outdoors to de-pot them, removing all of the soil in the pot and as much of it from around the roots as possible. Bring the plant indoors and, if possible, wash the roots to remove any eggs. If the pots are cheap plastic, I'd just toss the pot. Replant entirely in sterile potting soil, preferably in new pots.

If you can't toss the pots, clean them with soap and water and rinse thoroughly before repotting the plants. Water the plants thoroughly and remove any standing water in the saucer after 30 minutes.

Comment: I see it is going to be a pain getting rid of them...

Comment: Well, you could use pesticides, but I would not want to use them for plants that produce edibles. Also, it's possible that the insect isn't even eating your plant, so any pesticide applied to the plant would be wasted. Sometimes, the old-fashioned hand's-on way is best. I hope that you don't have dozens of plants to deal with.